# Netbeans error with glassfish server 3.1?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, netbeans7.0

I'm trying to launch a project in netbeans but I keep getting the error

"Could not connect to admin listener for GlassFish server 3.1
Verify that NetBeans can make outbound connections to localhost:4848"

I've been tackling glassfish server problems since morning. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: It's strange that you cannot launch the project, because that port is only used by admin portal, not by the project itself. Check if on port 8080 the project is deployed and running. Anyway the error you get seems caused by the firewall blocking port 4848...

Answer (score 6):

I encounted the same problem. It was because the server takes over the proxy settings of the IDE by default. You can deselect it by going to GlassFish Server 3.x properties and then click on the java tab ==> deselect Use IDE's proxy settings.

Afther that i could deploy my application.

Comment: This didn't solve all my problems, which were due to various problems, but it got me past the confusing bit of my deployment hanging without any log output, before timing out after 2 minutes and showing the error message mentioned in the question. Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked for me for the first step. Later I had to add my usename and password for another error message.

Answer (score 3):

Start server using:

```
<glassfilshInstallationRoot>\glassfish\bin\startserv.bat
```

For me it also works in NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to look at.

1) Make sure GF is running or if it's not that you can start it. On the Services tab, expand servers, right click on your gf server and select start.
2) Verify the port it's using by mousing over the server (see image). Make sure that port isn't blocked by a firewall.
3) Earlier you were having problems installing it. Right click on the server and verify the properties. If that path isn't correct or what not. Add a new server point to where ever you installed it.

[image: Glassfish admin port]

Answer (score 2):

I encounted the same problem today, cause I'm using it for rails, and I always use Webric to run rails project. If you don't use glassfish, you can just delete it.
 click 'tools -> service', and delete glassfish, then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me too,and I figured out  that the 'JavA(TM) Platform SE Auto updater ' service was not running.I  checked the service after running msconfig->startup tab.An update automatically was installed and there after everything restarted working.
Hope this might help.
Cheers.
Maiga

Answer (score 1):

The best thing that I suggest you can do is:

1. Download the separate source for Glassfish server application
2. Uninstall all the default files of Glassfish which were installed while installing Netbeans.(You need to close your Netbeans while uninstalling it. Plus delete any files in the folder glassfish-3.1.2.2 for which your path may be "C:programfiles/glassfish-3.1.2.2")
3. Install the new source of Glassfish into the folder glassfish-3.1.2.2 for which your path may be "C:programfiles/glassfish-3.1.2.2"

Finally, open your project in Netbeans. You will be able to see Glassfish server files. Build your file and run it.

Answer (score 1):

admin-listener port defined in domain.xml for glassfish should be same that of which netbeans is trying to connect, e.g. 4848 (default) as below:

```
<network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
</network-listeners>
```

location of domain.xml:

```
<Glassfish Installation folder>\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\<domain-name>\config
```

I had accidentally changed the admin port from 4848 to something else. Saving it to 4848 fixed the problem. I am not sure yet where configuration of netbeans resides for connecting GF admin port.

Answer (score 0):

same thing happend with me.then i checked my anti-virus setting and turned anti-virus firwall disable for some time.and then run my project again and it worked for me.
hope this may work for you as well.